# Localise qgis2web Leaflet output Measure tool

Tags: qgis, javascript, qgis2web, localisation

I just tested the measure tool in the leaflet output of the latest version of qgis2web plugin (2.28.0, QGIS 2.14.5LTR):

[image]

I've been trying to find a way to translate it to german and found that the `/qgis2web/js/leaflet-measure.js` contains a broad variety of languages, somewhere from line 6360... like

```
...
},{}],28:[function(require,module,exports){
// de.js
// German i18n translations

module.exports = {
  'measure': 'Messung',
  'measureDistancesAndAreas': 'Messung von Abständen und Flächen',
  'createNewMeasurement': 'Eine neue Messung durchführen',
  'startCreating': 'Führen Sie die Messung durch, indem Sie der Karte Punkte hinzufügen.',
  'finishMeasurement': 'Messung beenden',
  'lastPoint': 'Letzter Punkt',
...
```

way below (line 7048), I find some requirements, that might indicate that something is missing under `/qgis2web/i18n/`:

```
...
var i18n = new (require('i18n-2'))({
  devMode: false,
  locales: {
    'ca': require('./i18n/ca'),
    'cn': require('./i18n/cn'),
    'da': require('./i18n/da'),
    'de': require('./i18n/de'),
...
```

My last javascript experience is long ago, but are there some changes in the code that apply for a translation to german?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the exported file `index.html` in a text editor. and find the following code:

```
var measureControl = new L.Control.Measure({
    primaryLengthUnit: 'meters',
    secondaryLengthUnit: 'kilometers',
    primaryAreaUnit: 'sqmeters',
    secondaryAreaUnit: 'hectares'
});
```

Add another option as follows:

```
var measureControl = new L.Control.Measure({
    primaryLengthUnit: 'meters',
    secondaryLengthUnit: 'kilometers',
    primaryAreaUnit: 'sqmeters',
    secondaryAreaUnit: 'hectares',
    localization: 'de'
});
```

The supported languages are:

> en (default), ca, cn, da, de, de_CH, en_UK, es, fa, fil_PH, fr, it, nl, pl, pt_BR, pt_PT, ru, sv, and tr

The underlying plugin is https://github.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure, which is where I got this info from (I've tested to confirm it works).

Comment: hey, great! should more often have a look at github... Isn't this worth a little dropdown with all the languages in the next version of qgis2web to make localization easier for people like me?

Comment: Even better, perhaps I could detect the local language of QGIS, and insert the tag accordingly.

Comment: I know that I should avoid +1, but: +1

Comment: But what if I have a german QGIS and want a chinese leaflet map? ;-)